# Failures with Python multiprocessing.Pool when maxtasksperchild is set

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Python 2.7.8 on Linux and am seeing a consistent failure in a program that uses multiprocessing.Pool(). When I set maxtasksperchild to None, then all is well, when testing across a variety of values for processes.  But if I set maxtasksperchild=n (n>=1), then I invariably end with an uncaught exception.  Here is the main block:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = parse_cmdline()
    subproc = Sub_process(options)

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    [...]
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=options.processes,
                                maxtasksperchild=options.maxtasksperchild)
    imap_it = pool.imap(recluster_block, subproc.input_block_generator())
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    for count, result in enumerate(imap_it):
        print "Count = {}".format(count)
        if result is None or len(result) == 0:
            # presumably error was reported
            continue
        (interval, block_id, num_hpcs, num_final, retlist) = result
        for c in retlist:
            subproc.output_cluster(c, lock)
    print "About to close_outfile."
    subproc.close_outfile()
    print "About to close pool."
    pool.close()
    print "About to join pool."
    pool.join()
```

For debugging I have added a print statement showing the number of times through the loop.  Here are a couple runs:

```
$ $prog  --processes=2 --maxtasksperchild=2
Count = 0
Count = 1
Count = 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]reclustering.py", line 821, in <module>
    for count, result in enumerate(imap_it):
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 659, in next
    raise value
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

$ $prog --processes=2 --maxtasksperchild=1
Count = 0
Count = 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
[same message as above]
```

If I do not set maxtasksperchild, the program runs to completion successfully.  Also, if I uncomment the "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" line and enter the debugger, then the problem does not appear (Heisenbug).  So, am I doing something wrong in the code here?  Are there conditions on the code that generates the input (subproc.input_block_generator) or the code that processes it (recluster_block), that are known to cause issues like this?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you include the code for `recluster_block`? That's where the exception is coming from. If I had to guess, I would say using `maxtasksperchild` is subtly changing timing in a way that causes your `recluster_block` to hit some buggy code that it wouldn't otherwise hit. Try wrapping `rescluster_block` in a `try`/`except` block, and catch/log exceptions, rather than letting them escape to the parent.

Comment: multiprocessing is reraising the error from the child process. so, like @dano says, recluster_block is the primary suspect. logging the exception stack in the child would be interesting.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  It's hard to include the code for recluster_block because of dependencies. I wrapped recluster_block() and sure enough it is throwing "'int' object is not callable" every time when maxtasksperchild is set.  I'm thinking that's not what's really happening, but I'm not sure how to get deeper. Can you suggest how I can log the exception stack? Thx!

Comment: a quick hacky way for debug is to `import traceback` and then, in the exception clause, do `open('debugtrace.txt', 'a').write(traceback.format_exc() + '\n')`. That gives you the line that's failing and you can check from there.

Comment: With maxtasksperchild, multiprocessing keeps respawning the children. So, if you have dependencies on global variables and they have changed, the new spawn gets the new vars and boom. Also, if this happens to be windows, multiprocessing does some heavy lifting to pickle/ restore your environ in the child. that can lead to tears.

Comment: I logged the stack trace using `import traceback; traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)` in the exception-catching wrapper around `recluster_block`. It implicated this line of code: `for loop_cnt in count(): # itertools.count() yields 0,1,...`.  I replaced that call by `itertools.count()` and changed the import statement accordingly.  I really don't know why, but that solved the problem.  The exception is no longer being thrown, and the Pool.imap() iteratator is no longer barfing.  Thanks @dano and @ tdelaney!

Comment: search for `global count` in your main program. it seems like 'count' as the itertools function is replaced by an integer and that's one way it can happen.

Comment: okay, missed the obvious... `from itertools import count` and then a later `for count, result in enumerate(imap_it):` overwrites the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maxtasksperchild causes multiprocessing to respawn child processes. The idea is to get rid of any cruft that is building up. The problem is, you can get new cruft from the parent. When the child respawns, it gets the current state of the parent process, which is different than the orignal spawn. You are doing your work in the script's global namespace, so you are changing the environment the child will see quite a bit. Specifically, you use a variable called 'count' that masks a previous 'from itertools import count' statement.

To fix this:

1. use namespaces (itertools.count, like you said in the comment) to reduce name collisions
2. do your work in a function so that local variables aren't propagated to the child.